# Blazor Server localization not. Cannot find resources

Tags: localization, blazor, resources, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

My goal is to add localization to my Blazor Server application so I can change the language.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h82U0RQ9jtQ&t=3929s) and first tried to integrate this in a new project. This worked fine.
Then I wanted to integrate the code into my actual application. Unfortunately this does not work.
The problem seems to be that it can't find the resources.

I tried it again with two new applications and found out that it is because of the hyphen in the name. I think that this causes problems because the hyphen in the namespace is replaced with an underscore.

Both applications are server side in the .NET 6.0 framework.
One is called *EMV* and the other *E_M_V* as project and solution name.

The code I have added:

Added the Resources folder with the resource files: App.resx.
You only need one to recreate the problem. The problem is not the switching of the language, but that it takes the value from the given key.
I have a key called TestString and the value says *This is a Test*.

I have installed Microsoft.Extensions.Localization (7.0.0) and added it in the _Imports.razor.

This is my Program.cs. I commented which three parts I added:

```
using EMV.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Localization
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
// Localization


builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();


// Localization
RequestLocalizationOptions GetLocalizationOptions()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> cultures = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Cultures").GetChildren().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

    var supportedCultures = cultures.Keys.ToArray();
    var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

    return localizationOptions;
}
// Localization


var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();


// Localization
app.UseRequestLocalization(GetLocalizationOptions());
app.MapControllers();
// Localization


app.UseRouting();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.Run();
```

My Index.razor looks like this:

```
@page "/"

@inject IStringLocalizer<App> Localizer

<h3>@Localizer["TestString"]</h3>
```

This setup works totally fine in one project and not in the other. It only displays the resource key name.
I don't know if this is a bug or if I have to direct the ResourcesPath differently in my Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Assembly name and Default namespace in project properties are same. If they are not the same, then Blazor cannot find the translations.